# Could not resolve build failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I build new project in android studio java language and run the project 'app' then show me some sdk problem.

I updated the android studio and solve some sdk problem and it solved. But, it is giving me this problem build.

I have already checked lots of some question related to my problem but no luck.

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/indrays/AndroidStudioProjects/music_app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED

> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED

> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

Comment: have you tried deleting "build" folder and rebuilding it again?